# JPA hibernate partial one to many with join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have files and emails.
Some files get attached to emails, they get attached once.
I can achieve this with a table of attachments with just email_id and file_id.

Email entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "email")
    @JoinTable(
        name="attachments",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="email_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="file_id")})
    private List<File> files;

}
```

File entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class File {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Email email;

}
```

The thing is that not all files are attachments, so I don't want the `Email` entity in the `File` entity.
Is there any other way to achieve this? 
I was thinking inheritance possibly, were new entity `Attachment` extends `File`.

Update:

I probably should've explained a bit more: If I have `Case` that has a list of `File`, and `Case` also has a list of `Email` that has a list of `File`s as well, I'd have the files appear in 2 places in the `Case` entity. If I had an `Attachment` entity that is also a `File`, I'd have it so the entity couldn't be updated from there given that an email is sent, and I'd make the `File` undeletable. Thoughts?

Comment: In reality one email can have multiple files, so why don't you implement it that way. Have a one to many relationship from email to file. This don't mean you must have file(s) for the email. File could be 0 or more. Don't make it complicated. I don't see any  point in using inheritance in this context.

Comment: Associations don't have to be bidirectional. What you want is simply a unidirectional OneToMany association. BTW, the current mapping of your bidirectional association is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added a bit more to the question, can you guys have a look?